# Jackson - deserialize into runtime specified class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm writing a class that uses Jackson to serialize/deserialize objects. At compile time I don't know which is the type of the objects I will be serializing/deserializing.

I read a couple of articles and questions about the usages of `TypeReference` and `TypeFactory`, however I'm still having some issues.

My class looks like (removed some irrelevant code):

```
public class JsonSerializer<T> {

  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
  private TypeReference typeReference;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      typeReference = new TypeReference<T>(){ };
  }

  // ...


  public Object decode(CachedData cachedData) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(cachedData.getData(), typeReference);
    } // ...
  }
}
```

And this is the snippet of code I'm using to test this:

```
public class SerializerTest {

  private JsonSerializer<Clazz> serializer;
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
  private Clazz data = generateData(); // creates a simple object

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      serializer = new JsonSerializer<Clazz>();
      serializer.init();
  }

  // ...

  public void shouldDecodeDataCorrectly() throws Exception {
    CachedData cachedData = new CachedData(0, 
      objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data).getBytes(CHARSET), 
      CachedData.MAX_SIZE);

    Object object = serializer.decode(cachedData);
    assertEquals(data, object);
  }

  public static class Clazz {
    // POJO with getters and setters
  }

}
```

As far as I could understand, using `typeReference` should be enough to let know the deserializer that the value read from the byte stream should be put in a `Clazz` object. However, the object returned by the `decode()` method is still a `Map`, which I understand is the default class for deserializing.

I tried also changing the `decode()` method to return `return objectMapper.readValue(cachedData.getData(), objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(typeReference))`, but I'm getting the same problem.

I'm quite sure it's something regarding the way I pass the type into the serializer, but I haven't been able so far to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400850/is-jackson-really-unable-to-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear what exactly you are trying to do: much of the code does not make change. Specifically usage of `TypeReference` is wrong: you can not use type variables with it, type must be concrete.

However, perhaps solution is simpler than you thought. If you can keep track of original `Class`, just store that (or name from `clazz.getName()`), and pass that when deserializing.

Comment: This is an implementation of Couchbase `Transcoder`, which is a way to serialize/deserialize data before putting them into the cache. I'm using Jackson to serialize/deserialize JSON as a String, which then I'll convert into `byte[]` and put into a `CachedData` object. I tried passing the Clazz.class object into the `Serializer` and changing the call to `objectMapper.readValue(cachedData.getData(), clazz);`, but it still doesn't work - I'll update the question.

Comment: It worked now - I had to remove the default typing configuration I added before (after I posted the question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check @JsonTypeInfo ? Please have a look at it's documentation.

Comment: I cannot annotate the class - I think there should be another way of telling the 'ObjectMapper' to deserialize using a specific class?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the javadoc at http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.html
here is how I would do it:

Remove the typeReference field from JsonSerializer

Modify the JsonSerializer.decode method to take a type reference as an argument

Pass the type reference as an argument

```
Object object = transcoder.decode(cachedData, new TypeReference<Clazz>() {});
```

BTW - "transcoder" should be "serializer"?  Typo?

Comment: While legal usage, use of `TypeReference` here is unnecessary. Rather should just pass `Clazz.class` directly. `TypeReference` is only useful when you need to specify generic type parameters for things like `Map<String,Long>`.

Comment: I cannot change the signature of the method, however I'm able to pass the Class object for class Clazz. Still not working though, please have a look at the other comment. (yeah, serializer and transcoder are quite equivalent, I changed the code when asking the question and I forgot to change it in all the places!)