# Is Jackson really unable to deserialize json into a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, jackson, deserialization

This is a duplicate question because the following questions are either messy or they are not answered at all:

[deserializing-a-generic-type-with-jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118798/deserializing-a-generic-type-with-jackson)

[jackson-deserialize-into-runtime-specified-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355742/jackson-deserialize-into-runtime-specified-class)

[jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)

[jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659844/jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable)

I hope that this question will finally find an answer that makes this clear for good.

Having a model :

```
public class AgentResponse<T> {

    private T result;

    public AgentResponse(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

JSON input:

```
{"result":{"first-client-id":3,"test-mail-module":3,"third-client-id":3,"second-client-id":3}}
```

and two recommended ways of deserializing generic types :

```
mapper.readValue(out, new TypeReference<AgentResponse<Map<String, Integer>>>() {});
```

or

```
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(AgentResponse.class, Map.class);
mapper.readValue(out, javaType);
```

Jackson is never able to deal with the generic type T, it figures it's a Map from JavaType, but it finds Object type constructor argument because of type erasure and throws an error. So is this a Jackson bug, or am I doing something wrong? What else is explicit specification of TypeReference or JavaType for?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.fg.mail.smtp.AgentResponse<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@4f2d26d; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:984)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2064)
```

Comment: You should post that question on the jackson-users mailing list

Comment: Also, do you really try and deserialize _all_ that JSON or just this JSON's `result` member value?

Comment: I'm deserializing the JSON input into AgentResponse. I don't know how and why would I deserialize it partially. It's just a response with status and result value, that may be Object, collection, map, etc. I modified the question so there is just the generic result,

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to add some annotations on the constructor to tell Jackson how to build the object. The following worked for me:

```
public class AgentResponse<T> {

    private T result;

    @JsonCreator
    public AgentResponse(@JsonProperty("result") T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Without the `@JsonCreator` annotation, Jackson cannot know to call this constructor. And without the `@JsonProperty` annotation, Jackson does not know that the first argument of the constructor  maps to the `result` property.

Comment: Man you saved my day, I was debugging the jackson stack all the way down and I saw it found the constructor arguments, so I thought it was the generic problem. In fact the real problem was that jackson couldn't know the constructor argument names cause JVM doesn't provide it. Damn I should have try that without generics first... Thanks !

Comment: And if you are unable or unwilling to annotate the class directly, you can annotate a mixin instead: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Comment: Just a side point: if you have many parameters in the constructor you have to annotate all of them with @JsonProperty

Comment: is there any special code require to perform dezerialise ? or standard jackson derserialisation will work on the above approach ? I have seen people writing special derserialisation code with type reference, hence the question.

Answer (score 9):

I tried using the same approach but I haven't annotated my model class. It worked fine for me.

This is my model class

```
public class BasicMessage<T extends Serializable> implements Message<T> {
    private MessageHeader messageHeader = new MessageHeader();
    private T payload;
    public MessageHeader getHeaders() {
        return messageHeader;
    }

    public Object getHeader(String key) {
        return messageHeader.get(key);
    }

    public Object addHeader(String key, Object header) {
        return messageHeader.put(key, header);
    }

    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(T messageBody) {
        this.payload = messageBody;
    }
}
```

And I used the following method for deserializing the payload

```
public static <T extends Serializable> BasicMessage<T> getConcreteMessageType(String jsonString, Class<T> classType) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(BasicMessage.class, classType);
            return mapper.readValue(jsonString, javaType);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
 }
```

where jsonString contains the BasicMessageObject in a string.

Comment: +1 ... still you would loose immutability of the created object. Or is this also possible with private setters?

Comment: It looks we need to converters for all generic types in Java. This fixes inner type issue.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot! Had exactly the same issue with exactly the same message payload :)

Answer (score 3):

If you programmatically pick up the `java.lang.reflect.Type` from for instance a method return type or a field, then it is easiest to use

```
Type type = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField( "aKnownFieldName" ).getGenericType(); 
// or
Type type = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( "aKnownMethod" ).getGenericReturnType(); 


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType( type );
Object value = mapper.readValue( json, javaType );
```

A fully nested JavaType is created, so `Controller<PID<Temperature,Double>>>` will be deserialzed correctly.

Comment: please can you give an example of the Type type = ....;

Answer (score 1):

JSON string that needs to be deserialized will have to contain the type information about parameter `T`.
You will have to put Jackson annotations on every class that can be passed as parameter `T` to class `AgentResponse` so that the type information about parameter type `T` can be read from / written to JSON string by Jackson.

Let us assume that `T` can be any class that extends abstract class `Result`.

```
public class AgentResponse<T extends Result> {
    public Hits<T> hits;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImageResult.class, name = "ImageResult"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NewsResult.class, name = "NewsResult")})
public abstract class Result {

}

public class ImageResult extends Result {

}

public class NewsResult extends Result {

}
```

Once each of the class (or their common supertype) that can be passed as parameter `T`  is annotated, Jackson will include information about parameter `T` in the JSON. Such JSON can then be deserialized without knowing the parameter `T` at compile time.
This [Jackson documentation link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) talks about Polymorphic Deserialization but is useful to refer to for this question as well.

Comment: any idea What to do in case the class is Integer or any other built in class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AgentResponse<T> {

private T result;

public AgentResponse(T result) {
    this.result = result;
}
public T getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

}

So for the above class structure and T can be of Type T1,T2 class

So to deserialize for AgentResponse, use the following code

```
JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory.constructParametricType(AgentResponse.class,T1.class)
AgentResponse<T1> agentResponseT1 = objectMapper.readValue(inputJson,javaType);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Solution :***

Use TypeReference instead of class

```
 public T getObject(String json, TypeReference typeReference) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
     T t = (T) mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
      return t;
   }
```

***My Pojo Structure***

```
    public class SQSRequest<T> implements Serializable {    
    private T data;
    private String msgId;
    private String msgGroupId;
    .... 
}


        
 public class EmailDetails implements Serializable {
     private Map<String,String> paramMap;
        .... 
}
```

***Use***

```
SQSRequest<EmailDetails> req2=this.getObject(str, new TypeReference<SQSRequest<EmailDetails>>() {});
```