# Could not write JSON generic object

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

When I try to return a generic object i got a exception :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/administration/get_stat_all") 
public @ResponseBody
List<StatAllBean<String>>  get_stat_all(..) {

List<StatAllBean<String>> all_stats = new ArrayList<StatAllBean<String>>();
....
return all_stats ;
```

Here is my object :

```
public class StatAllBean<T> {

    public Map<T, Long> totalMap ;
    public Date date;
```

The exception :

```
19:14:56.366 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [<java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException>]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The all_stats list is an empty list, you need to check for that:

```
return ( all_stats.isEmpty() ? null : all_stats );
```

Comment: no it's not a empty list , i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400850/is-jackson-really-unable-to-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-type

Answer (score 0):

This is big hint "Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException"

Looks like something that you're passing along as is null. Are you initializing your map variable 'totalMap' before use?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400850/is-jackson-really-unable-to-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-type) so i edit my object lkike that :

```
public class StatAllBean<T> {

    public Map<T, Long> totalMap ;
    public Date date;


    @JsonCreator
    public StatAllBean(Date date , @JsonProperty("totalMap")  Map<T, Long> totalMap){
        this.date = date;
        this.totalMap = totalMap;

    }
    ...
```